# Insert where not exists, else return row

Tags: postgresql

I want to insert a row if it doesn't exist, else return the existing row. The following works fine for new rows, but it returns nothing in case the row already exist.

```
INSERT INTO product (brand, type)
SELECT 'aa', 'bb'
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT * FROM product WHERE brand='aa' AND type='bb'
    )
RETURNING *
```

I know a similar question had been asked before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18192570/insert-if-not-exists-else-return-id-in-postgresql), but the proposed solution (as I show above) doesn't work for me. In other words, this is not a duplicate question.

Comment: It seems you only read the first part of the answer in the linked question. To return the existing row, you need to use a construct similar to the query in the second part of the answer.

Comment: You are correct, I totally missed that. That second construct indeed works. Sorry for the confusion.