# Insert new row and get primary key or get primary key of existing record

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I have a simple tag table in Postgres 9.3:

```
CREATE TABLE tag (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  text TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE
);
```

Currently I can insert a new tag and get back the new id easily enough:

```
INSERT INTO tag (text) VALUES ('hey') RETURNING id
```

However I would like to check that the tag doesn't already exist (unique constraint) and if it does exist, return the id of the existing tag.

I attempted to use `COALESCE` to achieve this:

```
SELECT COALESCE(
    (SELECT id FROM tag WHERE text='hey'),
    (INSERT INTO tag (text) VALUES ('hey') RETURNING id)
)
```

But unfortunately while I believe this logic is sound it doesn't look like I can have an `INSERT` statement in a `COALESCE` (generates a syntax error at `INTO`).

What's the easiest way to accomplish this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Insert if not exists, else return id in postgresql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18192570/insert-if-not-exists-else-return-id-in-postgresql)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Return id if a row exists, INSERT otherwise](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10057668/return-id-if-a-row-exists-insert-otherwise)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit goes to [Clodoaldo Neto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/131874/clodoaldo-neto) for his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18192840/131874).

I'm putting my answer here because while his answer did point me in the direction it is slightly different, and I've simplified mine a bit.

```
WITH 
    existing AS (SELECT id FROM tag WHERE text='hey'),
    new AS (INSERT INTO tag (text) SELECT 'hey' WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM existing) RETURNING id)

SELECT id FROM existing UNION ALL SELECT id FROM new
```

Answer (score 0):

This should give you the same result.  If the row doesn't exist, then create it.  After that part executes, the row will definitely exist and we select its id.

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT id FROM tag WHERE text = 'hey')
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO tag (text) VALUES ('hey')
END
SELECT id FROM tag WHERE text = 'hey'
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't know the differences between PostgreSQL and MSSQL.  I should have looked into that before answering.  It is valid SQL for some platforms (MSSQL) so please be more specific with your criticism to make it more constructive.

Comment: It might be valid `T-SQL` but certainly not valid `SQL`. There is no `IF` statement in **SQL** (and no `BEGIN` or `END` either).

Comment: Got it.  From the syntax of the original post I inferred that it was t-sql or pl/sql.  Not trying to argue, just explain.  I'll keep this in mind in the future :)