# How to insert a row if not exists otherwise select and return its ID in both cases in MariaDB?

Tags: sql, select, insert, mariadb, unique

I have a table with `ID` primary key (autoincrement) and a unique column `Name`. Is there an efficient way in MariaDB to insert a row into this table if the same `Name` doesn't exist, otherwise select the existing row and, in both cases, return the ID of the row with this `Name`?

Here's a [solution for Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10079718/1915854). However, it seems MariaDB doesn't have the `RETURNING id` clause.
What I have tried so far is brute-force:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO services (Name) VALUES ('JohnDoe');
SELECT ID FROM services WHERE Name='JohnDoe';
```

UPDATE: MariaDB 10.5 has `RETURNING` clause, however, the queries I have tried so far throw a syntax error:

```
WITH i AS (INSERT IGNORE INTO services (`Name`) VALUES ('John') RETURNING ID)
SELECT ID FROM i
UNION
SELECT ID FROM services WHERE `Name`='John'
```

Comment: Have you seen this: [MariaDB: INSERT...RETURNING](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/insertreturning/)

Comment: @MaciejLos, will it return the rows that already existed, but would be inserted with `INSERT IGNORE`?

Comment: I have no idea. I have no access to MariaDB database.

Answer (score 1):

For a single row, assuming `id` is `AUTO_INCREMENT`.

```
INSERT INTO t (name)
    VALUES ('JohnDoe')
    ON DUPLICATE KEY id = LAST_INSERT_ID(id);
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

That looks kludgy, but it is an example in the documentation.

Caution:  Most forms of `INSERT` will "burn" auto_inc ids.  That is, they grab the next id(s) before realizing that the id won't be used.  This could lead to overflowing the max auto_inc size.

It is also wise not to put the normalization inside the transaction that does the "meat" of the code.  It ties up the table unnecessarily long and runs extra risk of burning ids in the case of rollback.

For batch updating of a 'normalization' table like that, see my notes here:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/staging_table#normalization  (It avoids burning ids.)